# Outlook 2003/2010 subject encoding

Tags: encoding, outlook, subject

'Received email message and subject contain german symbols, including **umlauts**(as 'ä', or 'ö'). Mail body is being displayed correctly, no problems with **umlauts**, but mail subject has problems with them:

- Outlook 2003: 'Bestätigung' is displayed as 'Besttigung'
- Outlook 2010: 'Bestätigung' -> 'ä' is dispayed as some unreadable symbol

How to make it display correctly?
P.S. Thunderbird displays subject with umlauts correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Outlook displays it that way, you cannot fix that - but wouldn't the problem be with the sender sending messages with a wrong encoding?
Or do you mean it is only displayed incorrectly in your own UI?

Comment: Then it probably attemnpts to correct invalid encoding. One way or another, it soundfs like the message encoding is wrong. Do you have access to the raw MIME message source in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was next: when creating mail, mail body was set encoding 'UTF-8', and subject was not.